# Difference between two forms of MVC route defination?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

**Form 1:** Define the default value of id in the action definition.

```
routes.MapRoute("MyRoute",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional});

public ViewResult Index (int id = 0)
{
    // ....
}
```

**Form 2:** Define the default value of id in the route definition.

```
routes.MapRoute("MyRoute",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = 0});
```

**My question:** I think that the two forms above get the same routing result in MVC routing system. But I don't understand the difference of them by my effort.

*(It's code snippet from relative source)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first, if a value for `id` is not provided in the URL, it will not be added to the view data.

In the second, if no `id` is provided a value of `0` will be assigned to `id`, which will be accessible in the view data

Comment: If there is another overload of action `Index` without parameters just like : `public ViewResult Index()` and the request URL is `Home/Index`, doest it route to the action Index() with the 1nd definition, route to the action Index(int id) with default id with the 2nd definition?

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot overload action methods by default in ASP.NET MVC.